# What does it mean "studying Torah as Moses did"?

Tags: talmud-gemara, torah-study, maseches-temura

[Temura 15b:](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Temurah.15b.35?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he)

> כל אשכולות שעמדו להן לישראל מימות משה עד שמת יוסף בן יועזר **היו למדין תורה כמשה רבינו** מכאן ואילך לא היו למדין תורה כמשה רבינו (*Sefaria doesn't have a translation*)

The discussion in the following Gemmorah is about the number of Halochos known. But nobody mentions a different way of learning or a different approach.

Which interpreters explain what it means "to study as Moses did" and "not as Moses did"?

Answer (score 3):

The Mishna in Sotah 9:9 (also 47a) talks about the end of the Eshkolos.
Rashi (DH ha'Eshkolos) in his commentary there says that there was no machlokes about Torah matters until that stage. This is similar to the way the Torah was given to Moshe, for whom there was never two opinions.

Apologies for not providing links, wrote this from my phone.

Comment: You're saying "Moshe was studying Torah without Macholokos". What does it mean? How a person can study with/without Machlokes? With himself?

Comment: There was no machlokes within the information being studied. Nowadays, you'll learn a gemara with Rabbi Meir vs Rabbi Yehuda. The Torah that Moshe studied didn't have two opinions on anything

Comment: How is it possible - we don't even agree on word meaning. See my new question on that: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100174/how-studying-torah-without-machlokot-is-possible